# Perform an if-else statement in Android, and the application crashes on button click

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently working on a currency converter in Android Studio. The error that I faced was that if I were to put the current input, which is "US Dollars" in the editTextCurrency box (enter currency box) and click on the convert button, the application would crash. However, if I were to put a wrong input for example "US" in the editTextCurrency(Enter currency box), the application did not crash but print out the message on the TextView which is intended to. I am not sure how I should solve this issue, I hope someone could point out the error that I made. Thanks.

kt file

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import edu.singaporetech.travelapp.databinding.ActivityCurrencyConverterBinding

/**
 * Activity that displays UI to convert currency
 */
class CurrencyConverterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCurrencyConverterBinding

    val TAG: String = "CurrencyConverterActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCurrencyConverterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.editTextCurrency
        binding.editTextRate
        binding.editTextSingDollar
        binding.currencyTextView
        binding.rateTextView
        binding.singdollarTextView
        binding.convertCurrencyButton
        binding.currencyOutputTextView

        binding.convertCurrencyButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.editTextCurrency.text.toString() == "US Dollars"){
                binding.currencyOutputTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                var currencyResult = calculateRate(binding.editTextSingDollar.toString().toFloat(), binding.editTextRate.toString().toFloat())
                binding.currencyOutputTextView.text = getString(R.string.display_currency, binding.editTextSingDollar.toString().toFloat(), currencyResult)
            }else{
                binding.currencyOutputTextView.text = getString(R.string.invalid_currency)
                binding.currencyOutputTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun calculateRate(value: Float, exchangeRate: Float): Float {
        // TODO What's the formula you need?
        return value * exchangeRate
    }
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currencyTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/currency"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCurrency"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/input_currency"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rateTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rate"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextRate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/input_rate"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singdollarTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/singapore_dollars"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSingDollar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/input_singapore_dollars"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/convertCurrencyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/convert" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currencyOutputTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="invalid_currency">Invalid Currency</string>
    <string name="display_currency">%.1f SGD is %.1f Singapore Dollars</string>

</resources>
```

Changes

```
binding.convertCurrencyButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.editTextCurrency.text.toString() == "US Dollars"){
                binding.currencyOutputTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                var currencyResult = calculateRate(binding.editTextSingDollar.text.toString().toFloat(), binding.editTextRate.text.toString().toFloat())
                binding.currencyOutputTextView.text = getString(R.string.display_currency, binding.editTextSingDollar.text.toString().toFloat(), currencyResult)
            }else{
                binding.currencyOutputTextView.text = getString(R.string.invalid_currency)
                binding.currencyOutputTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            }
```

Error message that I got from logcat

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

Comment: Can you add the thrown exception?

Comment: @mamo would like to know how to write the throw exception in this code as well as where to put it.

Comment: The thrown exception is the error stack trace you find in the log when the app crashes. It tells you what line of code made it crash and why

Comment: You will find your stack trace in Logcat: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: Usually when the application crashes the thrown exception is writed in the console, but if you can't see it you can try to add a try/catch statement and print the exception in except clause (reference here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html#checked-exceptions). I never used kotlin, but I think something like that

`try {
    // insert your if/else statement here
} catch (e:Expection) {
    e.printstacktrace()
}`

Comment: I have solved my issue. The issue was that I was not getting the text input. For anyone who faces the same error as me, I will post the error message I received from the logcat and upload the modified code that was my error.